# Show cinder quota usage for all projects?

Tags: openstack-cinder

There is `cinder quota-usage <tenant_id>` to show the quota usage for a particular project. Is there any way to show the usage of all projects with one command? Some sort of `--all` or so?

Answer (score 1):

Quotas are per project based, so cinder would not have that information, you have to query nova.

```
$ openstack quota show
```

Remember that part of the cinder related quota are, volumes, snapshots and backups, in order to query all the projects for that information you could script that, this is an example of how to do that.

```
$ for p in $(openstack project list -c Name -f value); do echo $p ; openstack quota show $p | grep 'backups\|snapshots\|volumes'; done
```